# How to create slider for Folium Circle Map

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, folium

I have a dataframe called df as below. It contains time series of the number of car passed (n) from Monday to Wednesday for two different locations, distinguished by the coordinate.

|  | day | lat | lng | 3pm | 6pm | 9pm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Monday | 3.1857 | 101.3153 | 24 | 50 | 35 |
| 1 | Tuesday | 3.1857 | 101.3153 | 13 | 36 | 49 |
| 2 | Wednesday | 3.1857 | 101.3153 | 29 | 63 | 58 |
| 3 | Monday | 3.1867 | 101.3145 | 7 | 15 | 32 |
| 4 | Tuesday | 3.1867 | 101.3145 | 5 | 21 | 18 |
| 5 | Wednesday | 3.1867 | 101.3145 | 19 | 24 | 42 |

And using `folium.Circle()` I managed to visualize how many car passed on 3pm on Monday:

```
df_day = df.loc[df['name'] == 'Monday'].reset_index(drop=True)

m = folium.Map(location=[3.185725088374699, 101.31522342062456], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=15)
  
for j in range(0,len(df)):
  n = df_day['3pm'].iloc[j]
 
  folium.Circle(
    location = [df['lat'][j], df['lng'][j]],
    tooltip = txt,
    popup = df['Addr1'][j],
    radius = float(n),
    color = 'black',
    fill = True,
    fill_color = blue
  ).add_to(m)

m
```

So what I am trying to achieve is visualizing the map using sliders so I can choose to display the number of car at specific time(3pm/6pm/9pm) and day(Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday).

The slider looks something like this: https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20220216223051/ezgifcomgifmaker.gif

But instead of date, I want to put the slider to choose from Monday and Wednesday, and another slider to choose time from 3pm to 9pm.

I am not really sure how to do that so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I can only find examples of folium sliders for time series columns. And the slider you want is a plotly slider, so it's impossible to realize it in folium. Please refer to the respective examples. [folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/TimeSliderChoropleth.ipynb) and [https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#sliders-in-plotly-express](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#sliders-in-plotly-express)